# CakePHP: content appended to blocks from a view loading first

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using view blocks to allow individual views to add scripts and stylesheets that are specific to those views. The resources that are used everywhere are included by default in the layout. Here's [the documentation on view blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks).

Everything works as described, but the content appended in my views was getting added BEFORE the default block content (even though I was using `$this->append('block name')`). After a lot of aggravation, I deduced that the views were actually getting referenced first, before the layout. So the scripts I was loading in the view were getting appended to nothing. Then the layout's scripts were getting appended afterwards.

I was able to solve this problem my removing my global scripts OUTSIDE of the block. But I don't like this approach for a couple reasons. In the future, I may want my view to be able to overwrite certain things. Also, it just seems wrong and counter to what view blocks are meant for.

My questions:
1. Is the behavior I described the intended behavior?
2. Is there a better work-around to manage script dependancies from scripts appended from views?

Answer (score 0):

I think blocks should not be defined in layouts, that's not the way it is intended for, it should be defined in views or elements, appended by other views or elements, and then **fetched** by layouts or views.

Comment: But the documentation clearly states that one of it's primary uses if for including scripts and other resources... and those almost always belong in the layout, right? This is supported by the fact that the default.ctp layout that comes out of the box is set up this way.

Comment: layout is rendered after view, so you can't define a block in layout, if you just want to append some js or css files, why not try `$this->Html->script('carousel', array('inline' => false));`, as the [document](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files) said?

Comment: If I do that won't the view's script get added BEFORE the global styles that are defined in the layout? Isn't this recreating the same problem I already have, just using cakePHP's built-in magic `->script()` block? For your suggestion to work, I would have to add ALL the scripts again and again in every view. Right?